# Gearman-Monitor could not connect to 7003

Tags: php

I installed gearman-job-server on my Linux server, and started the job server with mysql persistent queue on port 7003. Then I downloaded [Gearman-Monitor](https://github.com/yugene/Gearman-Monitor) and run it on an apache server, trying to monitor the status of the gearman server.

But when I visit Gearman-Monitor's index page, it says "Could not connect to: 7003". I seached on google but there's no clues. Could you please give some hints about this? Thanks.

Here's the PARAMS in /etc/init.d/gearman-job-server:

```
PARAMS="--port=7003 --queue-type=MySQL --mysql-host=127.0.0.1 --mysql-port=3306 --mysql-user=gearman --mysql-password=123456 --mysql-db=gearman --mysql-table=gearman_queue"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do some configurations in _config.php:

```
$cfgServers[$i]['address'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfgServers[$i]['name'] = 'Gearman';
++ $i;
```